# поиск файлов, модифицированных не сегодня

Tags: linux, find

Сохранить все файлы из директории за 7 дней, кроме текущей даты, **со всеми правами доступа и атрибутами исключая файлы текущего дня**

```
find /current/dir* -mtime -7 -type f -exec cp --preserve {} /mnt/backup/ \;
```

Вродебы так.

Вопрос: как исключить файлы из текущего дня?

Comment: Ищите опцию «только полные сутки».

Comment: Ага, это и так уже про полные сутки, тогда что-то думать с выражениями, типа *-mtime -7 -and -mtime +1*.

Comment: https://www.gnu.org/software/findutils/manual/html_node/find_html/Age-Ranges.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`-mtime -7` означает не «за семь дней», а «за 7*24 часов от текущего времени».

чтобы отсчёт был не от текущего времени, а от полуночи (фактически — от **следующей** полуночи), надо предварить опции `-mtime` (и аналоги) опцией `-daystart`:

```
$ find ... -daystart -mtime -7 ...
```

вот это и будет — «за последние семь дней включая сегодняшний».

а ограничить время «сверху» — как обычно — «с плюсиком, а не с минусиком»:

```
$ find ... -daystart -mtime -7 -mtime +0 ...
```

это будет «за последние семь дней, за исключением сегодняшнего» (т.е., фактически, за шесть суток).